# I'm creating a Altyrex program scheduler, to automatically open the Altyrex file and run it then close the file. It keeps opening the files infinitly?

Tags: python, automation, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

The program as mentioned should Open the file from the specified path, press "Ctrl" and "R" to run the file, then close said file. There are 2 types of operations a primary and a special: The primary is as described. The special does the same thing but then opens an excel file saves it and then opens another Altyrex file, runs it and closes it. My issue comes is when the first file is opened the program keeps on opening the file infinity without waiting for the specified interval. The program should reopen the file but after a set certain interval.

This is the primary file operation's function:

```
def execute_primary_file_operation(self, tab_state):
        try:
            logging.info(f"Starting primary file operation for {tab_state}.")
            file_run_time = tab_state.file_run_time
            file_path = tab_state.file_path
            os.startfile(file_path)
            logging.info(f"{file_path} opened.")
            
            time.sleep(tab_state.file_open_delay)
            
            max_retries = 5  # Maximum retries to find the window
            retry_interval = 2  # Time in seconds to wait between retries
            
            # Extract the name of the file without extension
            file_name_without_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]
            
            for i in range(max_retries):
                windows = gw.getAllWindows()
                
                # Using regular expressions to match the title that is held in Alteryx
                regex_pattern = re.compile(re.escape(file_name_without_extension), re.IGNORECASE)
                
                target_windows = [w for w in windows if 'Alteryx Designer' in w.title and regex_pattern.search(w.title)]
                
                if target_windows:
                    window = target_windows[0]
                    window.activate()
                    logging.info(f"{file_path} brought to the front.")
                    
                    time.sleep(tab_state.activation_delay)
                    
                    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')
                    time.sleep(file_run_time)
                    
                    window.close()
                    logging.info(f"{file_path} closed.")
                    return
                else:
                    logging.warning(f"Retrying to find Alteryx Designer window for {file_path}... Retry count: {i+1}")
                    time.sleep(retry_interval)
                    
            logging.error(f"Alteryx Designer window not found for {file_path}!")
            
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error in execute_primary_file_operation: {e}")
            logging.exception("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
```

This is the special file operation's function:

```
def execute_special_file_operation(self, tab_state):
        try:
            logging.info("Executing special file operation.")
            for file_path in tab_state.special_file_paths:
                file_run_time = tab_state.file_run_time
                file_open_delay = tab_state.file_open_delay
                activation_delay = tab_state.activation_delay

                os.startfile(file_path)
                logging.info(f"{file_path} opened.")
                
                time.sleep(file_open_delay)

                # Extract the name of the file without extension
                file_name_without_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]

                # Using regular expressions to match the title
                regex_pattern = re.compile(re.escape(file_name_without_extension), re.IGNORECASE)
                
                max_retries = 5  # Maximum retries to find the window
                retry_interval = 2  # Time in seconds to wait between retries
                
                for i in range(max_retries):
                    windows = [w for w in gw.getAllWindows() if 'Alteryx Designer' in w.title and regex_pattern.search(w.title)]
                    
                    if windows:
                        windows[0].activate()
                        logging.info(f"{file_path} brought to the front.")
                        
                        time.sleep(activation_delay)
                        
                        pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')
                        time.sleep(file_run_time)
                        
                        windows[0].close()
                        logging.info(f"{file_path} closed.")
                        break
                    else:
                        logging.warning(f"Retrying to find Alteryx Designer window for {file_path}... Retry count: {i+1}")
                        time.sleep(retry_interval)

                # Assuming that Excel operation is only needed after the first special file
                excel_file_path = self.get_latest_file(tab_state.excel_directory)
                if excel_file_path:
                    os.startfile(excel_file_path)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    pg.hotkey('alt', 'f4')
                else:
                    logging.warning("No recent Excel file found in the specified directory.")
                    
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error in execute_special_file_operation: {e}")
            logging.exception("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
```

This is the execute both operations function:

```
def execute_operation(self, tab_state, operation_type):
        try:
            with self.operation_lock:  # Acquire the lock
                if operation_type == 'primary':
                    self.execute_primary_file_operation(tab_state)
                elif operation_type == 'special':
                    self.execute_special_file_operation(tab_state)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"An error occurred in execute_operation({operation_type}): {e}")
            logging.exception("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
```

This is the loop file operations function:

```
def loop_file_operations(self):
        try:
            # Start the operation execution thread
            threading.Thread(target=self.execute_operations_from_queue).start()

            while not self.stop_refresh:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                current_time = now.time()
                
                # Loop through all special tabs
                for tab_name, tab_state in self.special_tabs.items():
                    self.update_timer(tab_state)
                    for special_time_str in [tab_state.special_time_1, tab_state.special_time_2]:
                        special_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(special_time_str, "%H:%M").time()
                        time_difference = datetime.timedelta(
                            hours=current_time.hour - special_time.hour,
                            minutes=current_time.minute - special_time.minute
                        ).seconds // 60

                        if 0 <= time_difference <= 5:
                            self.operation_queue.put((tab_state, 'special'))
                            break
                
                # Loop through all primary tabs
                for tab_name, tab_state in self.primary_tabs.items():
                    self.update_timer(tab_state)
                    start_time_str = tab_state.start_time
                    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time_str, "%H:%M").time()
                    interval = tab_state.primary_interval

                    time_difference = datetime.timedelta(
                        hours=current_time.hour - start_time.hour,
                        minutes=current_time.minute - start_time.minute
                    ).seconds // 60

                    if (0 <= time_difference <= 5) or (time_difference > 5 and time_difference % (interval // 60) <= 5):
                        self.operation_queue.put((tab_state, 'primary'))
                
                self.update_sidebar_timer()
                time.sleep(1)  # Consider adding sleep here to prevent high CPU usage

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"An error occurred in loop_file_operations: {e}")
            logging.exception("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Finally this is the execute operations from queue function:

```
def execute_operations_from_queue(self):
        while not self.stop_refresh:
            if not self.operation_queue.empty():
                tab_state, operation_type = self.operation_queue.get()
                self.execute_operation(tab_state, operation_type)
                self.operation_queue.task_done()
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure out why it keeps opening the files over and over again. I've tried looking through the code but I can't figure it out and I thought a pair of fresh eyes could be the solution. Thank you!

I've tried combing over the code but I've reached no conclusion. I don't have any theories we're very frustrated.